# Blender addon not appearing in Addon list after importing

Tags: mesh, scripting, add-on

I have an Addon I'd like to use in Blender 2.8. But when I would try and import the addon from my files, it wouldn't appear in the addon list so I could enable it. I've tried removing all dots (.) from the source file(s), and I tried manually putting the .py files in blenders file location for it's scripts-addons. Is there something I'm missing? Please help! The "modules installed" message posted below.
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors displayed on the console when you install your add-on? Why would you remove all dots from the file? That will break the script because Python uses the dot in it's syntax for accessing properties and functions of an object.

Comment: Sorry, I think I said that wrong. I didn't remove the dots from the python script, but the files folders and file names. I edited the main post and added what the message says above^.

Comment: Recommend for a commercial addon seeking support from where you obtained it.   @rjg There may be one top level folder with a dot that requires renaming, from the installer using zipfile name, and the download page naming the zip.

Comment: @batFINGER ah yes, that makes much more sense. The way I've read it initially was that literally all dots in the source have been removed.

Comment: I read it that way too.

Comment: I removed all the dots and it's still not wanting to import the addon. Even though it says it did.